# Command "october:migrate" is not defined

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I must add table to existing octobercms project and added migration but it is not migrating. what may be problem? when I type php artisan october:migrate I faced with  this problem

Command "october:migrate" is not defined.

Did you mean one of these?
october:down
october:env
october:fresh
october:install
october:mirror
october:passwd
october:up
october:update
october:util

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue: https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/5589

It looks like the `october:migrate` would be available once you updated to the version 2.

It is a paid one.

Answer (score 2):

`php artisan october:up` will only migrate the database

`php artisan october:update` will update the application files, plugins and migrate the database.

Check out this thread on the official forum
https://octobercms.com/forum/post/artisan-migrate

Comment: I tried php artisan october:up but it is not detecting new migration inside plugin